# Perform workflow step from visual web part

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow in which one of the step require user to fill out some data and then press "Submit" button. For all other steps I am using "Collect Feedback" action my workflow which opens InfoPath form for user to fill.

But I am trying to achieve this functionality using Visual Studio solution.

So let's suppose for this step I am assigning a task to that user who will receive link of page in email. That page contains web part with some fields and a submit button.

When user presses that button I want workflow to perform that step i.e.  user has completed his task.

How can I do that?

I suppose I will need to call workflow inside my code using some ID or workflow reference number and then I will need to iterate through workflow steps and once I reach that particular steps I will need to perform operation!?

SP is 2013 and workflow is based on 2010 created in SPD.